# Fortran can't read txt files created by another program

Tags: fortran

When i try to read a txt file with the following code example:

```
double precision inp(100)
open(1,file='whatever.txt')
do i=1,100
read(1,*) inp(i)
enddo
close(1)
```

The program just ends when it arrives at the read sentence. I tried alternative ways to write the loop, like

```
do
read(1,*) inp
enddo
```

but it's the same. The funny part is that if i write a txt with fortran or by hand and then i try to read it, it works!!

i'm desperate, please, help me.

Comment: Have you tried using a unit larger than 10? You're using 1, which might be already taken by something like standard in or something like that.

Comment: this should be closed as the issue was resolved and apparently unrelated to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas:

1. Take a unit number of 10 or larger, 1 might be taken by something like default i/o
2. Use `iostat` and `iomsg` to find out why the read fails:

   ```
   integer :: iostat
   character(len=100) :: iomsg

   read(unit=u, fmt=*, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) inp(i)
   if (iostat /= 0) then
       print *, "Error reading inp"
       print *, "i was ", i
       print *, "Error was: ", trim(iomsg)
   end if
   ```

Comment: At the end i changed one property of the file and it works, but thank you.

Comment: I cant really advocate adding all that extra `iostat` handling code to basically give you a prettier version of the error message the system would give you by default.

Comment: Even if you don't care about the added `iostat` handling during normal operation, I still think it's very useful for debugging. For example, without that handling, you wouldn't get the value of `i` when it crashes.